# Xcodeでcocos2d-xを使用したときに発生したエラー

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-x

> Cocos2d: cocos2d: cocos2d-2.1rc0-x-2.1.2
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL_VENDOR:     Apple Inc.
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL_RENDERER:   Apple Software Renderer
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL_VERSION:    OpenGL ES 2.0 APPLE-10.3.0
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE: 4096
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_UNITS: 8
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL supports PVRTC: YES
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL supports BGRA8888 textures: NO
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL supports NPOT textures: YES
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL supports discard_framebuffer: YES
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: GL supports shareable VAO: YES
>   Cocos2d: cocos2d: compiled with Profiling Support: NO
>   malloc: *** mach_vm_map(size=1048576) failed (error code=3)
>
>   *** error: can't allocate region securely
>   *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::bad_alloc: std::bad_alloc

どうすればこのエラーを取り除けますか？

Comment: もし可能なら、エラーの発生を再現できる小さなコードも併記されると、より解答がつきやすいかと思います。

Comment: おそらくメモリ不足ですね。何かしらループ中にメモリを解放せずに確保し続けていませんか？　3100 さんの仰る通り、最小限のコードで同様のエラーが起きる箇所を併記して頂けると的確にアドバイスできると思います。